# Show that $\operatorname {trace}(X\rightarrow R(X,Y)Z)=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle R(e_i,Y)Z,e_i\rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$\langle\,,\rangle$ is Riemannian inner,and R(X,Y)Z is curvature tensor.

How to show that $\operatorname{trace}(X\rightarrow R(X,Y)Z)=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle R(e_i,Y)Z,e_i\rangle$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A:V\to W$ is an operator and $f_i$'s is an orthonormal basis for $V$ then $$ trace A=\sum_k\langle Af_k,f_k\rangle $$
so for $A(x)= R(X,Y)Z$
$trace(X\rightarrow R(X,Y)Z)=trace A=\sum_{i=1}^n<R(e_i,Y)Z,e_i>$

Comment: Surely you mean $A:V \to V$. This formula is also only true when $e_i$ are an *orthonormal* basis with respect to $\langle ,\rangle$.

Comment: yes, you are quite right.

Comment: @RaziehNoori Why we have the formula? May I have a detail process?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709310/if-e-1-e-n-is-an-orthonormal-basis-why-does-operatornametracet?rq=1

Comment: @RaziehNoori Thanks.